# How to update Json file in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter. Sorry for so basic and simple question.
I know how to load/parse/read .json file. However I don't know what I have to do - if I want to change the content of .json file by tapping a button on the flutter mobile app, how can I do it?

I realized that I cannot pick a data and update content in the .json file, then what do I have to do?
I found a little (at least for me) information via searching like,

1. I cannot pick the specific content of .json and change it in the mobile app. I have to update the whole content of the .json file.
2. So I have to get help from something like SQLite.

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "value": 100,
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "value": 500,
    },
]

If I click button1 in Flutter mobile app, I want to change value 100 of id:1 to 200, and if I click button2 in-app, I want to change value 500 of id:1 to 600.
And this .json file has to be in the directory where I can see actually. (Means, if I use path_provider, .json file is not visible in android studio or explorer, ...)
And, this .json file has to be not deleted or changed, even if I quit the app.

I cannot explain it well. I really really appreciate your answer. Thank you.

Comment: read the whole file to string.... `jsonDecode` it, update the value however you want....encode it again....save to file.

Comment: @Ryosuke I'm sorry to repeat, but my point is I don't know how to "SAVE TO FILE" after encoding!... Can you help me with it? Thank you so much!

Comment: `file.writeAsString(encodedJson);`

Comment: @Ryosuke Ah now I see what you mean. Thank you so much for your help. I will try it, and I think it would work well! Thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

To update a json file, you can [decode](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-inside-model-classes) it first to an Object. A sample on that guide demonstrates parsing a json response, mapping it to `User` class.

```dart
class User {
  final String name;
  final String email;

  User(this.name, this.email);

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = json['name'],
        email = json['email'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'name': name,
        'email': email,
      };
}
```

Here,`User.fromJson` can be called to parse the json data.

```dart
User currentUserData = User.fromJson(httpResponse);
```

You can then update the data by setting values to the User object. Either using current data from the json response, or passing a new value. Let say we're going to update the email address.

```
User updateUserData = User(currentUserData.name, newEmailAddress);
```

Then call `jsonEncode` to parse the data back to json.

```
String json = jsonEncode(updateUserData);
```